# how do i merge two elements from array in javascript depending on the date (or whatever the element is similar to)

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash

my current array looks like this

```
array = [
 {
  date: '2020/06/12',
  hours: 8.4
 },
 {
  date: '2020/06/15',
  hours: 4.5
 },
 {
  date: '2020/06/12',
  hours: 3.8
 },
 {
  date: '2020/06/16',
  hours: 5.5
 },
]
```

so the whole idea is to sum and filter those days that are repeated, like the array from above, the day 12 is duplicated, so we sum the hours, the result should be like this

```
array = [
 {
  date: '2020/06/12',
  hours: 12.2
 },
 {
  date: '2020/06/15',
  hours: 4.5
 },
 {
  date: '2020/06/16',
  hours: 5.5
 },
]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a reducer:

```
const result = array.reduce((acc, cur) => {
   const prev = acc.find(elem => elem.date === cur.date);
    if(prev) {
        prev.hours += cur.hours;
    } 
    else {
        acc.push(cur);
    }
    return acc;
}
, []);
```

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: array = [
 {
  date: '2020/06/12',
  hours: 8.4
 },
 {
  date: '2020/06/15',
  hours: 4.5
 },
 {
  date: '2020/06/16',
  hours: 5.5
 },
]

Comment: the result didn't sum the hours, but the date was filtered

Comment: It works fine, check here: https://jsfiddle.net/eo5ay98c/  Share the whole snippet if the error persists, it might be something else affecting the result.

Comment: yep my bad, it works, is that react native for some reason is displaying twice a value, but the console result is working fine

Answer (score 0):

```js
const groupBy = (arrayOfObjects, property) => {
  let i = 0;
  let val;
  let index;
  const values = [];
  const
    result = [];
  for (; i < arrayOfObjects.length; i++) {
    val = arrayOfObjects[i][property];
    index = values.indexOf(val);
    if (index > -1) result[index].push(arrayOfObjects[i]);
    else {
      values.push(val);
      result.push([arrayOfObjects[i]]);
    }
  }

  const newArray = [];

  for (const x of result) {
    let total = 0;
    let datex;
    for (const obj of x) {
      datex = obj.date;
      total += obj.hours;
    }

    newArray.push({
      date: datex,
      hours: total,
    });
  }

  return newArray;
};

// Call the groupBy function
const answer = groupBy([{
    date: '2020/06/12',
    hours: 8.4
  },
  {
    date: '2020/06/15',
    hours: 4.5
  },
  {
    date: '2020/06/12',
    hours: 3.8
  },
  {
    date: '2020/06/16',
    hours: 5.5
  },
], "date");

console.log(answer);
```